# Stuck in Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Tags: python, django, git-bash

I made my project fine and when I run my server through a normal shell, it works. Now, I am trying to run my project through Git Bash. All the commands seem to work fine but when I do `python manage.py runserver`, it gets stuck on

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

Apparently after that I go to `localhost:8000` but that and my 127 port 8000 are not responding and show that there's nothing there. What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be missing the port binding, try to run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to be sure that the app is running on localhost:8000

Answer (score 8):

If you use django with Dockerfile, you won't miss that env var PYTHONUNBUFFERED set by 1.

Comment: its `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` not `PYTHONBURRED` env var

Answer (score 1):

Using Git Bash run:

$ python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

In my case, it showed the same behavior ('Stuck in watching...').
However, after that I opened a browser and I typed:

127.0.01:8000.  The Django webpage works properly.

Answer (score -1):

Probably autoreload does not work well in your environment, if you don't need it - better turn it off by starting django with --noreload arg.

Comment: Hi there, it's best to leave hypotheses about what *could* be the problem as a comment, and not as an answer. Answers should be more fact-based and certain. Once you have more reputation, you'll be able to provide comments